# About Greediness regex in python

Tags: python, regex

Why does the ‘?’ In python regex work for the characters after and not before?

```
import re 

string = "From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008"

x = re.findall("\S+?@\S+" , string)
print(x)
```

—————————————————-

```
import re 

string = "From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008"

x = re.findall("\S+@\S+" , string)
print(x)
```

Why does the first and second cod e print the same the exact same thing even though the first code has the “?” Which removed the “greediness” of “\S”.

In other words why doesn’t the first code print “d@uct.ac.za”?

Comment: Because there is *no way* for the second code to match anything without letting go of the matches in the first `\S+`. As far as I'm aware, any regex flavour would act the same here. Can you give an example where this regex works differently?

Comment: I guess you shouldn't call something *weird* when you don't understand it fully. The regex expression you provided has *nothing* to do with python and does not act weird at all.

Comment: I believe that the question has value in it but the selected wording is really poor. I suggest  'What does laziness mean in regex and why does it not affect the start of the matched pattern?'.

Answer (score 3):

Non-greediness doesn't affect where the match starts, only where it ends. `\S+?` means "stop as early as possible without invalidating the match". Since the `\S+?` is followed by `@\S+`, "as early as possible" means "before the first @ you see followed by at least one non-space character".

So given the input `abc@def@ghi`, `\S+@\w+` would match the whole string (with `\S+` matching "abc@def" and `\w+` matching `ghi`), whereas `\S+?@\w+` would only match `abc@def` (I replaced the second `\S+` with `\w+`, so it doesn't match the second @).

Answer (score 0):

## Lazy matching

With `\S+?@\S+` will try to match match non-space characters until it reaches an `@` them match more non-space characters. So with the string "From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008" it will first attempt matching "**From** stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008" which conforms to `\S+?` but it then the match fails because it's not followed by `@`.

The next place that `\S+?` can start matching is starting with "stephen" where:

1. `\S+?` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^
```

- The following character is not an "@", so the regex engine adds the "t".

2. `\S+?` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^^
```

- The following character is not an "@", so the regex engine adds the "e".

3. `\S+?` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^^^
```

- The following character is not an "@", so the regex engine adds the "p".

...

16. `\S+?` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- The following character **is** an "@", so the regex engine stops lazily consuming input for `\S+`. The engine continues with the next part of the pattern.

17. `@` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
                     ^
```

- This works. The engine continues with the next part of the pattern.

18. `\S+` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

- This works. This is the end of the pattern.

The pattern is satisfied.

## Eager matching

With `\S+@\S+` the first `\S+` and `@` overlap. In that case, the regex engine will try to satisfy `\S+` and consume any `@`. If it cannot satisft a match, it will start releasing the characters one at a time to verify if the consumed input doesn't actually conform to the pattern.

With "From" the results are identical - it doesn't match because it doesn't have an "@" sign.

Let's look at how the match happens for "stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za":

1. The first `\S+` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- The following character is not an "@", so the regex engine lets go of the final "a".

2. The first `\S+` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- The following character is not an "@", so the regex engine lets go of the final "z".

3. The first `\S+` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- The following character is not an "@", so the regex engine lets go of the final ".".

...

10. The first `\S+` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

- The following character ***is*** "@". There is no further backtracking. The engine continues with the next part of the pattern.

11. The `@` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
                     ^
```

- This works. The engine continues with the next part of the pattern.

12. The second `\S+` will match

```
From stephen.marquard@uct.ac.za Sat 5 09:14:16 2008
                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

- This works. This is the end of the pattern.

The pattern is satisfied.